# can $\sin(n)$ be arbitrary small?

Tags: calculus

I know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(n)$ does not exist. But can $\sin(n)$ be arbitrary small? More formally: Let $\varepsilon>0$. Is there exist a **positive integer** $n$ such that $|\sin(n)|<\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: You can prove that $\underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}\sin(n)$ is *dense* on it's value space meaning it will assume values arbitrarily close to any value that it takes. I think Jack has the details of what is required for that, I don't remember them right now.

Comment: @TheSubstitute, he mentioned $n$ is an integer (Otherwise, trivial)

Comment: Would you guys please look up the meaning of "positive integer $n$"? It's written clearly enough in the question. So $n$ is neither continuous not passing through $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Weyl's equidistribution theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128/how-do-you-prove-that-pn-xi-for-xi-irrational-and-p-a-polynomial-is-un) implies that the fractional part of $M\pi$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$.

Thus if $M\pi = n + f$ with $f \to 0$, then $f \gt \sin f= |\sin(M\pi -f)| = |\sin(n)|$

This shows that $|\sin(n)|$ can get arbitrarily close, infinitely often to any value in $(0, \sin 1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Because the zeros of $\sin$ are the elements of $\pi\mathbb{Z}$ and $\sin$ is continuous, your question is equivalent to have for every $\epsilon>0$ positive integers $p$ and $q$ with $|q\pi-p|\leq \epsilon$. But this is possible by  [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem).

Comment: Thanks @sigmabe. Can you please elaborate your answer? Why it is equivalent?

Comment: @boaz I hope my edit helps for understanding.

Comment: Thanks, it's helps!